# I need to use QuickDraw API in my project

Tags: api, artificial-intelligence, system, backend, project

In the beginning I am really sorry for me English.
I want to use QuickDraw [API](https://quickdraw.withgoogle.com/#) for my project. I need ways to:

1. Get random category ( for exmaple cat, apple etc. ). I mean by that just availables words for that AI system.
2. Send "drawing" in the correct format and check what AI system recognized.

I need features above because I want to create a simple multiplayer game in which players draws the current category and the player who drew it first wins.

I was looking for informations but I couldn't find what I really need.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The [Quickdraw dataset README](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/quickdraw-dataset) has excellent instructions on how get the data in multiple format. You should be able to easily pick a random category from Quickdraw's [categories.txt](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/quickdraw-dataset/blob/master/categories.txt)

Regarding the AI system, you might need to roll your own.
There are multiple resources available:

- [TensorFlow Quickdraw RNN Classification Tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/tutorials/sequences/recurrent_quickdraw.md) (though I [had some trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774035/how-to-classify-a-quickdraw-doodle-using-tensorflows-sketch-rnn-tutorial) with this one)
- [DoodleNet](https://github.com/yining1023/doodleNet)
- [Kaggle Quick, Draw! Doodle Recognition Challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/quickdraw-doodle-recognition/)

If you have a look at the bottom of the QuickDraw dataset readme there are links to other resources, including (classification related) papers as recent as 2020.